Byte-wise iteration through an array in generic function in Ada
I have an array in a generic function where I want to iterate through it byte by byte. In the following example I am using Wide_Wide_Character's, so a character is 4 bytes long. With 3 given input characters, I would have 12 bytes to iterate through. How can I achieve this? Thanks for your time.
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Test is

   generic
      type T is (<>);
      type T_Index is range <>;
      type T_Array is array (T_Index range <>) of T;
   function A (b : T_Array) return Integer;

   function A (b : T_Array) return Integer is
   begin

      --  how can I iterate here through each byte instead of "byte blocks"?
      --  should be 12 bytes in this example (3 characters * 4 bytes)
      --  can I map b to System.Storage_Elements.Storage_Array (without copying it)?
      for I in 1 .. b'Length loop
         Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (b (T_Index (I))'Image);
      end loop;

      return 1;
   end A;

   function A1 is new A (Wide_Wide_Character, Positive, Wide_Wide_String);

   unused : Integer := A1 ("abc");

begin

   null;

end Test;


This can be done. The recommended way is to introduce a nested loop as shown in the example below and convert each array element to a storage array.
Converting the array b to a storage array as a whole in one go is discouraged as an array may not be contiguously stored in memory if the index type is an enumeration type represented by non-contiguous values. In such case, the array may be stored in memory with "holes"  depending on the compiler implementation.
test.adb
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Unchecked_Conversion;
with System.Storage_Elements;

procedure Test with SPARK_Mode is

   generic
      type T is (<>);
      type T_Index is range <>;
      type T_Array is array (T_Index range <>) of T;
   procedure A (b : T_Array);

   procedure A (b : T_Array) is

      package SSE renames System.Storage_Elements;
      use type SSE.Storage_Count;

      Num_Storage_Elems : constant SSE.Storage_Count :=
        T'Size / SSE.Storage_Element'Size;

      subtype T_As_Storage_Array is SSE.Storage_Array (1 .. Num_Storage_Elems);

      --  Conversion per array element.
      function To_Storage_Array is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion
        (Source => T, Target => T_As_Storage_Array);

   begin
      for Elem of b loop
         for Storage_Elem of To_Storage_Array (Elem) loop
            Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Storage_Elem'Image);
         end loop;
      end loop;

   end A;

   procedure A1 is new A (Wide_Wide_Character, Positive, Wide_Wide_String);

begin
   A1 ("abc");
end Test;

output
$ test
97
 0
 0
 0
 98
 0
 0
 0
 99
 0
 0
 0


This is inherently non-portable. The order you encounter the bytes will typically depend on the processor's endianness, for example. Presuming you want to process the bytes in platform order, you have several options:
A. If System.Storage_Unit = 8, then System.Storage_Elements.Storage_Element is a byte, and you can use Ada.Storage_IO to convert your (suitably constrained) subtype to and from the constrained subtype of System.Storage_Elements.Storage_Array that an instance of Storage_IO provides. So you could write
function To_Bytes (S : in Wide_Wide_String) return System.Storage_Elements.Storage_Array is
   subtype Local is Wide_Wide_String (S'range);

   package S_IO is new Ada_Storage_IO (Element_Type => Local);

   Result : S_IO.Buffer_Type;
begin -- To_Bytes
   S_IO.Write (Buffer => Result, Item => S);

   return Result;
end To_Bytes;

and a corresponding conversion back to Wide_Wide_String;
B. If Storage_Unit /= 8 (very rare these days), then you will have to define your own byte type, and create operations similar to those in A. but using Ada.Unchecked_Conversion.
C. If and only if measuring the result of using A. or B. shows that the copying involved causes the program to not meet its timing requirements, you can replace the conversions with an overlay:
S : Wide_Wide_String (1 .. Length);

subtype S_As_Bytes is Storage_Array (1 .. Length * Wide_Wide_Character'Size / 8);

B : S_As_Bytes with Address => S'Address, Import, Convention => Ada;

and then iterate over B. This is very poor practice if done unnecessarily.
